# Formatting of quark fields

Tags: notation, quarks

I try to follow the ISO 80000-2 norm when typesetting physics. This is more a typesetting question but I did not want to ask this at the TeX SE site since this only applies to physics and I am not concerned with the implementation of formatting but the formatting itself.

In Section 3 of ISO 80000-2, the authors write:

> Variables, such as $x$, $y$, […] are printed in italic […] type. […] The same applies to functions in general, e.g., $f$, $g$.

From this I would conclude that I shall write a spinor $\phi$ in italics.

But then there is, also in Section 3:

> An explicitly defined function not depending on the context is, however, printed in Roman […] e.g. $\sin$ […]

Then in a [TUGBoat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf) I read

> 8. Chemical symbols coincide with the names of
>      the nuclides if they carry proper sub and superscripts; with respect to typography, particles
>      and quanta are treated as the nuclides. They
>      are made up of one or two letters and must be
>      set in roman type [6, section 4];

This makes me think that I should write the pion content as $\mathrm{u \bar d}$ and not $u \bar d$ in text. This is somewhat like a chemical equation of the contents of the hadron.

Calling a function $g$ instead of $f$ does not make any difference. But the quarks have fixed names, therefore one has to write them upright in text, right?

But what about an equation where the quark names actually stand for spinors, say something like
$$ \mathcal L = \bar u (\mathrm i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m ) u \,.$$
Would it be better to use
$$ \mathcal L = \bar{\mathrm u} (\mathrm i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m ) \mathrm{u}$$
instead? The same applies to kaons which I can either write $K(p)$ or $\mathrm K(p)$.

In QFT, there are the $u$ and $v$ spinors as solutions to the Dirac equation. $\psi(\vec x, t)$ is given in terms of those $u$ and $v$ spinors. Since the up-quark spinor would be $u(\vec x, t)$ or $\mathrm u(\vec x, t)$, it might be a bit strange, although I doubt that anyone in the field would seriously stumble over this.

What would be a good way to typeset the quarks, especially in the role of spinor fields in the Lagrangian?